# awk - incrementing one column but keeping the rest of the column intact

Tags: awk

I have another question

I have this dataset

`1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;`

Below is the result I want:

`1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|5;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|6;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|7;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|8;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|9;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|10;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|11;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|12;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;`

I'm using this snippet of code

```
for file in /cygdrive/c/work/studies/project/data/trim/"$datenow"/*v3.tsv; 
do
awk -F\| '$1!=l{c=$2}{$2=c++}{l=$1}1' OFS=\| "${file}" > "${file%.*}v4.${file##*.}"
done`
```

However, it is not working the way I'm expecting as it only gives me this

`1955|1
1955|2
1955|3
1955|4
1955|5
1955|6
1955|7
1955|8
1955|9
1955|10
1955|11
1955|12
1956|1
1956|2`

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited:** I've tried all the possible variations but it is not giving me the results I'm expecting, with `-F\|` and `OFS=\;` or `-F\;` and `OFS=\|` but to no avail

Comment: Just going a bit crazy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk -F"[;|]" '{$2=c++%12+1;sub(/;/,"|")}1' OFS=\; file
1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|5;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|6;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|7;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|8;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|9;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|10;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|11;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|12;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
```

This version does not change any formatting.

```
awk '{sub(/\|[0-9]+/,"|"c++%12+1)}1' file
1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|5;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|6;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|7;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|8;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|9;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|10;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|11;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|12;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
```

It just replace the number after `|`

Comment: I want to keep the `|`, Jotne. Is it possible? My file is bound by semicolon and by having an extra, it is creating havoc in my dataset.

Comment: @AndyK fixed the missing `|`

Comment: You need a sub for substitute ... ok. Let me have a try.

Comment: Working as treat. Awesome, Jotne.

Comment: This will fail if every year **does not** have 12 rows. Hope thats what OP wants.

Comment: Ok everyone.

Double check. It will be working fine. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1!=prev{c=0} {sub(/^[^;]+/,++c,$2); prev=$1} 1' file
1955|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|3;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|4;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|5;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|6;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|7;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|8;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|9;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|10;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|11;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1955|12;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|1;.;.;.;.;.;.;
1956|2;.;.;.;.;.;.;
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I was eyeing for ... though mine was not as idiomatic as this one is! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

A very similar, but equally effective answer:

```
awk -F"[;|]" 'OFS=";" {$2=a[$1]+++1;sub(/;/,"|"); print}' file
```

**Explanation**

Define two possible field separators ; and |

> -F"[;|]"

Define a single output field separator ;

> OFS=";"

Replace the content of the second field (after the pipe) with an array indexed by the first field that increments with each occurrence

> awk -F"[;|]" 'OFS=";" {$2=a[$1]+++1

substitute the first FS ; with |

and print

> print

Comment: You have `FS=";"` in the condition area of the awk script. That statement will be evaluated once for every line of input, which is not desirable. Move it out of the script to a `-v` assignment, or put it in a `BEGIN` section. Some white space or parens in `+++` would help show what you're doing with that statement.